# why cannot access arraylist from other class?

Tags: android, list, arraylist, nullpointerexception

In webservice class, it will retrieve database from online and put into list:

```
public List<List_NewsComment> allCommentList;
public void GetCommentNews( final int gCommentNewsID)
{
    Thread networkThread=new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){

            try
            {
                SoapObject request= new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,get_Comment_METHOD_NAME);
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransportSE= new HttpTransportSE(URL,60000);

                request.addProperty("itemid", gCommentNewsID);
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                androidHttpTransportSE.call(get_Comment_SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
                RetrieveFromSoap( result);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };
    networkThread.start();

}

public List<List_NewsComment> RetrieveFromSoap(SoapObject soap)
{
    allCommentList= new ArrayList<List_NewsComment>();
    Vector<Object> property2 = extracted(soap);

    for (int i = 0; i< property2.size();i++){

        SoapObject getPropertyD=(SoapObject)property2.get(i);


        List_NewsComment addcomment= new List_NewsComment();
        addcomment.setcommentDate(getPropertyD.getProperty("date").toString());
        addcomment.setUserName( getPropertyD.getProperty("name").toString());
        addcomment.setCommentContent(getPropertyD.getProperty("comment").toString());

        allCommentList.add(addcomment);
    }
    webservice.allCommentList.size();        <-- can call here no problem
    return allCommentList;
}

private static Vector<Object> extracted(SoapObject soap) {
    return (Vector<Object>)soap.getProperty(0);
}
```

In Main Activity class, i want to check the size of list:

```
Database_WebService webservice = new Database_WebService(this);
    webservice.GetCommentNews(newsid);
webservice.allCommentList.size();            <-- cannot call here, what is the problem
```

It returns me `nullpointerexception`.

What is the problem????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `List static` so you can access it anywhere using that class name .

### Like

```
public static List<List_NewsComment> allCommentList;
Database_WebService.allCommentList.size();
```

### Or

As everyone suggest make one function in your class and return the size of array in that function. Please see code below.

```
public int getCommentListSize()
{
    return allCommentList.size(); 
}

then call this method as

Database_WebService databaseWebservice = new Database_WebService(this);   
int size =databaseWebservice.getCommentListSize.size();
```

Comment: Static does not enforce correct object-oriented programming, and the way that the variable is being accessed isn't the problem, it is never initialised.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not initialized is because it is being initialized within the thread, so the sequence of events goes like this:

1. `GetCommentNews` starts
2. The thread starts
3. Now the thread and usage of list size (that's broken) is being run at the same time

You cannot use `allCommentList` until after the thread has finished execution, so you need to signal or do something with `allCommentList` within the `RetrieveFromSoap` method after it has been assigned.

Also you should not make the list static, this goes against the principles of object-oriented programming, and you should expose `allCommentList` through a getter not directly with a variable.

**Edit:**

You may actually be better off staying away from `Thread` and using an `AsyncTask` instead, this class was designed to make doing UI work from a `Thread` easier.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        int count = urls.length;
        long totalSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
            publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
        }
        return totalSize;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
    }
}
```

Reference: [AsyncTask | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Right,Correct,Excellent Answer...Just Need to edit one moretime..with the thing that **make your method GetCommentNews return type int/boolean and return something at end 1/true so the control waits there until its done**

Comment: Also you need to change your attitude bro..Should never talk/comment this way..hope you will delete those

Comment: Yeh nothing wrong..but this "Revenge downvote, mature Chirag" is not good.

Answer (score 0):

Because List allCommentList is not initialized there it will initialize inside the public List RetrieveFromSoap(SoapObject soap).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<List_NewsComment> allCommentList;
int size =Database_WebService.allCommentList.size(); 
--------------------------------------------------
```

still i recommended don't not good to use static better to make one **method**

```
public int getArrSize()
{
    return allCommentList.size(); 
}
```

then call this method as

```
Database_WebService dvws = new Database_WebService(this);   
int size =dvws allCommentList.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very ugly, why not add a method like 'int webservice.getCommentsSize()' and return the size, so you could test if the list is not empty and you don't need direct access.

like:

```
class Webservice{
 private List allCommentList = null;
 public int getCommentListSize(){
  if(allCommentList==null) return 0;
  return allCommentList.size();
 }

}
```

in main:

```
 Webservice webservice = new Webservice();
 int size = webservice.getCommentListSize();
```

another problem is, that your list probably won't be ready at the time you try to get it's size. Why are you running this in a thread? Have you seen AsyncTask ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful as you are **creating** the List in a diferent thread (networkThread) from where are you calling it (from the main thread). You should be sure that networkThread has finished before accesing it from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `ArrayList` static. Then you can get access using classname.YourArrayList from the other class.